# Calculate/Predict the future center of a frame with SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, scale

Swift 5.2, iOS 13

I want to predict/calculate the centre point of a frame after it has been scaled so I can move a shape to it while scaling it. If I try to scale and center an view in an animation/dynamically it doesn't work, with the end result a combination of center points I suspect.  So in the images below, the blue box starts in the top right hand corner, I scale and move it to the center. But as you can see from the green box, the scaling has messed up the point it needs to get to...

[image] [image]

```
struct SwiftUIView2: View {
@State var relocate = Alignment.topTrailing
@State var zoom:CGFloat = 1.0
@State var tag:Bool = true
@State var tag2:Bool = false
@State var centerPoint: CGPoint = .zero
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ZStack(alignment: relocate) {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                    if self.tag {
                        self.zoom = 2.0
                        self.relocate = Alignment.center
                    } else {
                        self.relocate = Alignment.topTrailing
                        self.zoom = 1.0
                    }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        self.tag.toggle()
                    }
                    
            }
            .scaleEffect(zoom, anchor: .topLeading)
        }.frame(width: 256, height: 256, alignment: relocate)
            .border(Color.red)
        if !tag {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.tag.toggle()
                    }
                }.frame(width: 256, height: 256, alignment: .center)
                    .scaleEffect(zoom, anchor: .center)
        }

    }
}
}
```

GeoReader I thought would be the answer, but I get garbage from it too. Spent more than a week trying custom alignments, position, everything I can think of. Eyeballed a solution with screen site percentages for now, but obviously it doesn't work too well with different sized screens.

Comment: I see *how* do you do it, but I can't understand *what* are you trying to achieve. Is it zoom-in from top-right corner to center of screen? I'd might propose different approach if I know the goal.

Comment: @Asperi yes, it is too zoom in from top-right corner to the centre of the screen. So top right small, center large. Center large back to top right small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fix (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
            }
            .scaleEffect(zoom)      // << here !! (remove topLeading anchor)
        }.frame(width: 256, height: 256, alignment: relocate)
```